# Is it necessary to disable root login and password login in sshd_config when no password set?

Tags: security, passwords, key, sshd

According to [Why is root login via SSH so bad that everyone advises to disable it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82626/why-is-root-login-via-ssh-so-bad-that-everyone-advises-to-disable-it), to avoid brute force password cracking, we disable root and password login (by setting `PermitRootLogin` & `PasswordAuthentication` to `no` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).
But if we didn't set any passwords and will never set them (login only with key), is it still necessary to disable root and password login?

Comment: The linked question is on another site. This question should be too.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that in many situations root can't log in anyway with ssh.  So you don't in theory have to deny root.  However, it's bad practice to rely on *implicit* security measures.  *Explicit* is always better.

Say for instance, one fine day, you do create a root password, or change something else that might open up root login. Are you smart enough to keep track of all the implicit security you have based on root not having a password? I'm not. So I deny root.